# Html DIV not aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to align 3 html div horizontally using CSS, I used `display: inline-block` but it is not working. I also tried changing the div wrapper to unordered list and it did align horizontally, but every time I try to style the **+** sign, the `div` alignment is reverting back to vertical. Kindly check the code below and let me know the best solution for this.

**HTML using div as wrapper**

```css
#freqboughtwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.freqitem1 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('acer1.jpg')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.freqitem2 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('hdmi1.jpg')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.freqitem3 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('monitor1.jpg')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Frequently bought together</h3>
<div id="freqboughtwrapper">
  <div class="freqitem1"></div> +
  <div class="freqitem2"></div> +
  <div class="freqitem3"></div>
</div>
```

**HTML using ul as wrapper**

```css
#freqboughtwrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.plussign {
  size: 10px;
}

.freqitem1 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('acer1.jpg')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.freqitem2 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('hdmi1.jpg')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.freqitem3 {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('monitor1.jpg')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Frequently bought together</h3>
<ul id="freqboughtwrapper">
  <li>
    <div class="freqitem1"></div>
    <p class="plussign"> + </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="freqitem2"></div>
    <p class="plussign"> + </p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="freqitem3"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest keeping it as using a div as a wrapper. If you include `display: flex` instead of your `display: inline-block` on the `#freqboughtwrapper`, it should give you the layout you require.

Also, you mentioned styling the + sign, you will probably need to wrap that in a div so you can target just this icon. (Depending on how you want to style it).

```css
#freqboughtwrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.freqitem1 {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.freqitem2 {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}

.freqitem3 {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x50')no-repeat;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Frequently bought together</h3>
<div id="freqboughtwrapper">
  <div class="freqitem1"></div> +
  <div class="freqitem2"></div> +
  <div class="freqitem3"></div> +
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution solved the alignment but the images are now not appearing. It only displays +++

Comment: @ReynardJoseph you just need to add in widths for your images :-) I've amended my answer above. *Please note*: I've amended the wrapper from `width` to `min-width` so that it doesn't cut your images off.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex-box this way:

```
.freqboughtwrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between; //if you want them equally spaced out and spread out.
  justify-content: space-evenly; // If you want them on equal distance from boundary and each other
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use flex option

```
.divclass
{
     display:flex;
}
```

You Can Have Brief Tutorial Here
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/